# Prove or disprove $\mathbb{Q}[x] /(x^5-3) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x] /(x^5-9)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Want to prove or disprove this

$\mathbb{Q}[x] /(x^5-3) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x] /(x^5-9)$ as communtative rings.

I can show that $x^5-3$ and $x^5-9$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$, but I cannot go from there.

I have guessed going from $\mathbb{Q}[x] /(x^5-3) \cong \mathbb{Q}(3^{\frac{1}{5}})\cong \mathbb{Q}(9^{\frac{1}{5}}) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x] /(x^5-9)$, but I am not sure about whether $\mathbb{Q}(3^{\frac{1}{5}})\cong \mathbb{Q}(9^{\frac{1}{5}})$ holds.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see some of the numbers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]3)$. We clearly have $\sqrt[5] {3}$. So we must have its powers
$$ \sqrt[5] {3}, \sqrt[5] {9},\sqrt[5] {27},\sqrt[5] {81}.$$
And so in particular, we can see that
$$ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{9}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5] 3).$$
Since both are degree five extensions, this subset relation must actually be an equality. So
$$ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{9}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5] 3),$$
finishing your proof. $\diamondsuit$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Calculate $(\root5\of 3)^2$ and $(\root5\of 9)^3$.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^5-3)$, clearly $x^2+(x^5-3)$ is a root of the polynomial $X^5-9$.
On the other hand, in $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^5-9)$, $x^3+(x^5-9)$ is a root of $X^5-9^3$ so that $\frac13x^3+(x^5-9)$ is a root of $X^5-3$.
We conclude that $x\mapsto x^2$ and $x\mapsto \frac13x^3$ induce field homomorphisms in both directions, which must be isomorphisms.